# Fix/Replace DNN search-engine with FTP

Tags: search, content-management-system, dotnetnuke, google-custom-search

I'm working on a DNN website, I have a user account with Admin privileges but don't have access to the Host Account. I do have FTP access and have been browsing around the file-structure and have seen some files referring to search.

The search is not working on the website so I was hoping I could replace the back-end code which runs the search, via FTP.

What files would need to be replaced to make sure they are not corrupted/buggy.

I realize doing this may not solve the problem, so any other advice as to trouble-shooting or possible solutions are appreciated.

*EDIT(For those asking how in what way search does not work):*

*Here is an image of what happens when I search 'sheep' (the website is all about sheep). Was told by the company that original website that the search runs on our pages 'Keywords'. I've made sure pages contain keywords but they still do not show up in search.*

[image]

Comment: It would be much more helpful to also outline exactly how search is not working. Otherwise, we'd be simply guessing. :)

Comment: I've updated the question to try to explain, let me know if there is any other information that would be useful.

Comment: Okay... The problem was never solved though. :(  Without host access, you'd need to have SQL Server access. My first guess is that you needed to enable the search engine scheduled job.

Comment: In my opinion the problem was solved. The title says 'fix/replace' and it has indeed been replaced. From my previous experience with this CMS, I'm guessing the built-in search-engine's results would be worse then that of Google.

Comment: Agreed. Few search solutions can compete with Google. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up using for this problem because I could find no other solution without having the Super-User account access. Was to implement Google's Custom Search Engine, with the multi-page option.

http://www.google.com/cse/

In my case the original search engine was working via GET command with a value of q. This is the same as Google's CSE multi-page option. So I was able to simply remove the old search results html from a module and replace it with the html snippet provided by Google.